# Large image copy to canvas using drawImage causes large memory usage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a large image that is 23552px by 8192px that is used as a way to combine many 1024px by 1024px individual images into a single image, something similar to how sprite images are used to combine icons/assets.

I am loading that image using the Javascript `Image` object.

Then I copy one of the 1024 x 1024 tiles out of the big image, and into an offscreen canvas of the same size, 1024 x 1024, using drawImage.

Then, I copy that offscreen canvas onto another offscreen canvas of the same size using drawImage.  Normally, in my real world application, this second canvas is actually the on screen canvas, but to simplify the reproduction of the problem, I just kept this second canvas off screen.

The drawImage from the first canvas to the second causes a roughly 700MB increase in memory usage in both Chrome and Firefox on Mac.  I have not been able to figure out why it is such a large amount, but have this very simple use case that causes it.

The 700MB usage after several seconds gets garbage collected, so I do not think it is a memory leak, just a huge memory usage.  In my real world case, the 700MB of usage is putting some people out of memory on their machine and causes them to get the dreaded "Aw Snap!" in Chrome.

Here is a link to the code below on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zz4iFK?p=preview) and the image I am using is on [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d3li.png).  On Plunker you can pull up Activity Monitor or whatever you use to monitor memory usage, then click the Button to start running the code below, and watch the memory usage of the process increase by > 700MB.

```
  function drawcanvas() {
    var oImage = new Image();
    oImage.onload = function() {
      console.log('image loaded');

      // tile size in pixels, the image loaded is 23552 x 8192, which has 23 x 8 tiles
      var tileSize = 1024;

      // create a canvas that is not on DOM
      var hiddenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      hiddenCanvas.width = tileSize;
      hiddenCanvas.height = tileSize;
      var hiddenContext = hiddenCanvas.getContext('2d');

      // create another canvas that is not on DOM
      var masterCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      masterCanvas.width = tileSize;
      masterCanvas.height = tileSize;
      var masterContext = masterCanvas.getContext('2d'); 

      // 1) drawing one tile, 1024 x 1024, from the big image into a canvas that is 1024 x 1024
      //    this causes negligible memory increaase by itself
      hiddenContext.drawImage(oImage, 0, 0, tileSize, tileSize, 0, 0, tileSize, tileSize);

      // 2) copy the 1024 x 1024 canvas into another canvas that is 1024 x 1024
      //    this causes about 700MB of memory usage in both Chrome & Firefox on Mac
      masterContext.drawImage(hiddenContext.canvas, 0, 0, tileSize, tileSize, 0, 0, tileSize, tileSize);

      console.log('processing done');
    };
    oImage.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d3li.png";    
  }
```

Comment: I must assume you're coding only for the desktop because an image that large will swamp mobile devices. Desktops usually have GPU's with their own GPU memory. Your image is so large you are probably exhausting the GPU memory so the GPU must use other memory resources to accomplish rendering -- hence your memory usage. While having a huge spritesheet simplifies your coding requirements, it burdens your user's devices. I would recommend recoding to not use your huge spritesheet.

Comment: @markE You are right, this will only be on the desktop.  But using 700MB seems to be quite excessive to me, that's one of my curiosities.  23552 x 8192 = 192 million pixels.  So to get 700MB, it would have to be storing 4 bytes per pixel, which I guess is 1 byte for each channel rgba.  But what doesn't make sense is why does it read the entire image into memory on the 2nd drawImage call, which I'm only moving 1024 x 1024 pixels between two canvases?  At that point it shouldn't matter what the original image size was.

Comment: Yes, the image is stored as a primitive bitmap so you are correct that the image "costs" 23552x8192x4. If GPU memory is exhausted (and it probably is with that large an image) then in order to fetch your 1kX1k subsection, the entire imageData must be re-read to pull that subsection out. I firmly recommend recoding to not use your huge spritesheet. I know a huge spritesheet makes your coding life easier, but it's not really fair to your users. ;-)

Comment: 23552px by 8192px - cripes! - that will exhaust most PC memory. I think you need a different approach...

Comment: Each 1k x 1k tile represents a different set of data that will be stacked on top of each other to visualize it all together.  Each layer may be selectively hidden and custom colored, 1k x 1k is a practical resolution to show it at with typical desktop resolutions, so hence the tiled image to make it so that just one network request needs to happen yet we still have individual access to each layer.  Just happens there are 23 * 8 sets of data which makes a big initial image to get all the data in.

Comment: @JeremyZerr. Understood -- you are using large images. Your single huge spritesheet **is NOT the way to go**. One alternate: Break up your huge spritesheet into many much smaller spritesheets and require that the user download those spritesheets to local drive in advance of using your app. Refactor your code to smartly load the appropriate spritesheet(s) as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **23552 by 8192 is Too Big**

Like everyone said. Way Too BIG. It is also impossible to see any more pixels at one time than the device's display res. So not only is the RAM use to great, most of the RAM used is not even viewable as pixels, either combined into single pixels when zoomed out or off screen when zoomed in.

**There is always a solution**

Any browser can display any resolution image Eg [365 Gigapixels](http://www.in2white.com/), any browser can be used to create an image of any resolution (if you are prepared to wait)

I have a lot of experience with browser and client side scripting for canvas, but I am not an expert in this particular field. See last paragraph for what should be the first stop on the path to solving your problem. The rest I present is a conceptual solution and only one of many possible solutions.

**A possible solution**

Op you said you want to visualize the data contained in the 23*8 184 tiles.

You can not store that many tiles as `Image` on anything but top end machines. You can however load them as needed and once cached loading will be quick.

The user can only see as many pixels as the display can display so the image used to display the data should not exceed the display resolution. You have a wide image format (Aspect 2.875:1), so I assume you will want to pan horizontally. We can accommodate the wide format as it is not that far out to present problems (images over 2-3 times the display max res should be considered too big)

As the image is such a high resolution it is fair to assume the user will have the ability to zoom in and see pixels at a one to one resolution.

So the case will be for a 1080HD display at full res (full screen).

Create the offscreen canvas (OSC) at the correct aspect to fit 1080 * 2.875 3105*1080 (The pixel budget for the offscreen canvas). As all scaling I assume is to be uniform we can use the natural image vertical res (VR= 8192) as our referance for calculations, which is 8192. We will referance the zoom via the virtual vertical resolution VVR. For full zoom (pixels one to one) that would be VVR = 8192, for half it would be VVR = 4096, to see the image so that all display pixels are used (scale to fill) that would be VVR = 1080 (the display resolution). To see all of the image (scale to fit) the VVR = Math.min(Display Res Hor / 23552, Display Res Vertical / 8192) * VR = ~0.0815 (Note the top and bottom of the display will be empty, in this case)

You use VR to calculate the tile scale TS = VVR/VR. Then you load each tile as an image and render that image using at scale TS on to the OSC. At scales under (VVR < vertical display res (1080)) you will need to load all 184 tiles to have the full image, at other scales (zooming in) the number of tiles will reduce. Only load what can fit on the OSC, always start loading tiles at the center of the view. When zooming use the OSC to draw back on itself at the new scale so that there is some feedback for the user while you wait for the tiles to re render. When panning while zoomed or zooming out, render the OSC back on itself so you keep the tiles already loaded and load only the missing tiles at the edges for panning, or load first the edge tiles then center when zooming out.

You could afford another off screen canvas to hold the visible part of the current OSC to stop some feedback artifacts that can occur when rendering to self but you should subtract the RAM for that canvas from the Rule Of Thumb available RAM for tiles (see further down this doc for details on RAM budget).

More on this in *Notes 1, 2*

That is the basics of how to present large format image data sets.

### **Some ways to improve this solution**

**Loading and refreshing the offscreen canvas.**

In the perfect world with the OSC at the same res as the full image, zooming will be smooth and real time. The solution presented unfortunately has some unwanted artifacts, when zooming in the display can become blurry, when panning and zooming out pixels at the edge will be missing and need to wait for tiles to fill. This is unavoidable.

**Anticipate and Pre-load tiles**

You can improve the time to refresh the OSC by anticipating what the users is going to do and preload tiles ready if that action does indeed occur. The number of pre loaded tiles will depend on the available RAM. As you can not know how much is available (browsers do not provide that information) you can use a rule of thumb calculation to get the number.

**RAM budget rule of Thumb**

To calculate the RAM budget for tiles. The RAM to store an image at the device display resolution * 9. So if the screen resolution is 1920 * 1080 then the display RAM is 1920 * 1080 * 4 = 8Mb then times 9 (3*3) to give 72Mb. Then divide and floor that by the tile RAM 1024 * 1024 = 1MB for ~72 tiles and you can be reasonably assured that the device will have that available (Note that devices with low resolutions are likely to be budget conscious devices and the ratio of display size to available RAM will be lower. I reduce the multiplier from 9 to 4 (2*2)

**Multi resolution Tiles**

You can increase tile loading performance by creating many different tile sets. The base tile set are at 1024 * 1024 pixels (full res) but when zoomed out most of the pixels are lost. Rather than load in 4 tiles to draw them all at half size, pre render a new tile set at that zoom so that one 1024 by 1024 tile holds 4 original tiles, thus you only need to load 1/4 as many tiles.How many tile set you create is will be dictated by the many factors, doubling the resolution for each set is the simplest but you need to load tile at a higher res if the user stops at a zoom not matching a tile set. When at max zoom out the tile set may not match that zoom. As it is fairly easy to play with and server/cache storage is plentiful the best result can be found via experiment (and user case studies, similar to note 2 at the bottom of the doc)

**ENCODED or DECODED images**

The image stored in the cache/storage device is an encoded representation of the image. The encoding usually includes compression (lossy for jpg/webp and lossless for png/gif..) When you create and load an image the pixels are decoded to create the bitmap. The decoded image is much larger than the encoded image, storing the 184 tiles as decoded Images is pushing the RAM limits, but you can store the encoded images as BASE64 in a 8 bit typed array. You can also do a simple and quick BASE64 to binary stream packing on the BASE64 (as BASE64 does not use 6 bits of every 3 bytes encoded) so that the typed array size matches the image disk size. You can load the encoded images via AJAX or fileloader

If you do not require the alpha channel for the tiles use JPEGs. JPEGs at "high quality"  or quality setting 50 has a average compression of around 15:1 (for RGB) and 20:1 for RAM rgba (Loaded Image()). At this quality compression artifact just start to become visible to the casual observer. At this compression the full tile set will need ~40Mb to store all tiles as encoded bit packed JPEGs well within the RAM budget for the case solution machine res of 1920by1080

A **warning** is associated with storing encode images in RAM. Javascript is not consistent across browsers and even across browser versions when it comes down to instructions per second. As this method uses the same small number of instructions 100s of millions of times even the most minor performance factors can have major consequences on the over all loading and presenting the BASE64url to the Image.src for decoding. You should thoroughly test any attempts to implement this method across as many browsers, browser versions, devices and device CPU types as you expect to be used. It should be tested against loading encoded image from cache/local disk. Only use this method where there is a clear benefit. As it is not a large bit of code to do this you can selectively use this method only for platforms that give a benefit in performance.

So to end where you should start... :)

### **Where to start**

**Off the shelf solutions**

All that is a lot of work and there are enterprise and open source solutions for this type of image display that are worthy of investigation and should be the first stop before implementing your own solution. I have only presented some of the ways to improve the application in terms of avoiding excessive RAM use (and browser crashed) There is a lot more involved and a lot of time spent by others building and optimising this type of application and I am by no means an expert in this particular field and shopping around will be a benefit even if it just gives you a few tips.

---

**Note 1**

When zooming in you can change the off screen canvas resolution if the data to be viewed is likely to induce a lot of vertical panning, make it taller, if the panning is expected to be any direction make it square, if the panning is to be mainly horizontal keep it wide.

**Note 2**

If your app is server based record all panning by all users as two numbers. Number of pixels panned for horizontal (HP) and for vertical (VP). At the end of session send the stats to the server where you then divide HP/VP to get a pan direction ratio for all users. If this ratio is near 1 you know to create a square off screen canvas when zooming, if much greater than 1 you know user are more likely to pan horizontally so keep the wide aspect, and for less than 1 make it taller (don't go over the pixel budget))

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer.  I think what we'll have to work on is a blend of server/client solution.  Right now, most of the burden is on the client, which has more memory limitations than the server.  So I think we'll have to maybe push a little more off to the server and have it help pre-combine/stack some of the data to reduce the size of the image/data that we have initially get to begin the client side part of the processing.